# What happens in the patched version of 2 Worlds if the final boss is killed by peasents

Tags: version-differences, two-worlds

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NeR-bT3uv0&ab_channel=GamesDoneQuick) speedrun, we see the game ending in under 3 minutes, when the player provokes the final boss to attack some villagers, who in turn maul him to death.

The player mentions that he's using a non-patched version of the game because this was fixed later. I am not planning to buy this game any time soon to try myself so what happens in the patched version of the game if the same trick is attempted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this discussion on the game's Steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1930/discussions/0/1696043263501568814/), the boss in invincible and the villagers all eventually die.

Comment: that's dissapointing